# PL/SQL function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to PL/SQL. I have this error:

[image]

Error at line 5: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculeaza_total_incasari RETURN NUMBER IS
        incasari NUMBER;
        BEGIN
        nrutilizatori:=calculeaza_total_utilizatori;
        SELECT  sum (p.pret) into incasari from rezervare r,planificare p , film f where f.idfilm=p.idfilm and r.idplanificare=p.idplanificare 
        RETURN incasari/nrutilizatori;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('Nu sunt incasari');
    END;
```

How can I replace that line?

Comment: please provide the schema for `rezervare `, `planificare ` and `film`

Comment: You haven't declared the variables `nrutilizatori` and `calculeaza_total_utilizatori`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to declare the `nrutilizatori` parameter, and initialize it like this: `nrutilizatori := calculeaza_total_utilizatori();`.

Don't forget to put all semicolon `;` characters after select statement.

Try the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculeaza_total_incasari RETURN NUMBER IS
      incasari NUMBER;
      nrutilizatori number;
    BEGIN
      nrutilizatori := calculeaza_total_utilizatori();
    SELECT  sum (p.pret) into incasari from rezervare r,planificare p , film f where f.idfilm=p.idfilm and r.idplanificare=p.idplanificare; 
    RETURN incasari/nrutilizatori;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Nu sunt incasari');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculeaza_total_incasari RETURN NUMBER IS
    incasari NUMBER;
nrutilizatori NUMBER;
    BEGIN

    nrutilizatori:=calculeaza_total_utilizatori();
    SELECT  sum (p.pret) into incasari from rezervare r,planificare p , film f where f.idfilm=p.idfilm and r.idplanificare=p.idplanificare;
    RETURN incasari;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Nu sunt incasari');
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Edit] I just noticed that this question was asked a few months back. I will leave my answer since it could be useful for other users.

Since you are using aggregate function SUM you do not need exception handler - no_data_found will never be raised. If you expect to have no rows returned, wrap SUM with NVL or else you will get NULL value, in which case the return result will also be NULL.

Other than that you did not declare nrutilizatori variable, have syntax error (you did not write ';' after the select statement) and a possible logical/numeric error - if it is possible for a function calculeaza_total_utilizatori to return 0 you will get division by zero error, and if it can return NULL your final result will also be NULL.

Another additional comment - functions have to return value in all cases, including exception handler blocks, else you will get ORA-06503 error 'Function returned without value'. This won't happen in your case because no_data_found will not be raised, but you have to keep this in mind for future development.

The complete function is as follows (without checking what calculeaza_total_utilizatori function returns), although I don't understand this function/query (nor calculeaza_total_utilizatori) - why no input variables? It looks as if you could just sum everything from planificare table, without joining it to other tables. Not sure if this is really the requirement...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculeaza_total_incasari RETURN NUMBER IS
  incasari NUMBER;
  nrutilizatori NUMBER;
BEGIN
  nrutilizatori := calculeaza_total_utilizatori;

  SELECT NVL(SUM(p.pret), 0)
    INTO incasari
    FROM rezervare r, planificare p, film f
   WHERE f.idfilm = p.idfilm
     AND r.idplanificare = p.idplanificare; 

  RETURN incasari/nrutilizatori;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a quite better way to write the code (Check it ahead).

By the way, NO_DATA_FOUND exception is almost impossible to be raised, because a query with aggrupation function will always return a single row if the query doesn't have the GROUP BY clause.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculeaza_total_incasari RETURN NUMBER IS
  incasari      NUMBER;
  nrutilizatori NUMBER;
  ret_value     NUMBER;
BEGIN
  <<total_incasari_bk>>
  BEGIN
    nrutilizatori := calculeaza_total_utilizatori;
    SELECT  NVL(SUM(p.pret), 0)INTO incasari from rezervare r,planificare p , film f where f.idfilm=p.idfilm and r.idplanificare=p.idplanificare;
    ret_value := incasari/nrutilizatori;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('Nu sunt incasari');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
  END total_incasari_bk;

  RETURN ret_value;
END;
```